# Inject the revision number in sourcecode (TortoiseSvn or SVN Shell)

Tags: python, perl, svn, version-control, tortoisesvn

I would like to inject the revision number in source code on commit.
I found out that I could do it through svn shell by doing something like:

```
find . -name *.php -exec svn propset svn:keywords "Rev"
```

However someone else said that that would not work as there are no files in the repository (as they files are encrypted), and I should be able to do it in tortoiseSVN. I found the "Hook Scripts" section, but I have completely no experience with this stuff.

Could you give me some indication how the command should look like, if I would like to have the first lines of code look like:

```
/*
*    Version: 154
*    Last modified on revision: 150
*/
```

I know that you could inject by using $ver$ but how to do it so only files in certain directories with certain extensions get this changed.

Answer (score 4):

Don't write your own method for injecting version numbers.  Instead,

- only introduce the replaced tags `$Revision$`, [etc.](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.advanced.props.special.keywords.html)) in the files you want the replacement to happen for
- only enable replacement (using `svn propset svn:keywords Revision` or some such) for those files